# DB Subnet Group doesn't meet availability zone coverage requirement. Please add subnets to cover at least 2 availability zones. Current coverage: 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have created two subnets for rds but still, I am getting error  DB Subnet Group doesn't meet the availability zone coverage requirement. Please add subnets to cover at least 2 availability zones. Current coverage: 1, As I can check my both subnets, even all of my subnets are getting created in the same availability zone. Can you Please guide me

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rdssubnet" {
  name       = "database subnet"
  subnet_ids = ["${aws_subnet.rds_subnet.id}","${aws_subnet.rds_subnet1.id}"]
}


#provision the database
resource "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  identifier             = "database"
  instance_class         = var.db_instance_type
  allocated_storage      = var.db_size
  engine                 = "mysql"
  multi_az               =  false
  name                   = "Database "
  password               = var.rds_password
  username               = var.rds_user
  engine_version         = "5.7.00"
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.rdssubnet.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds.id]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create your `aws_subnet`, you have to specify AZs where to place them. There is a special attribute for that called [availability_zone](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/subnet#availability_zone). For example:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "rds_subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "rds_subnet1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b"
}
```

Comment: Region thank you for your response but region is variable in my script and is passed at run time so its not possible to hardcore availability zone in code. is there any other way.

Comment: @AnkitSingh Hi. You can automatically get the AZs using [aws_availability_zones](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/availability_zones).

Comment: I don't understand why `multi_az` can be `false` but this requirement still obtains? it seems like https://github.com/terraform-community-modules/tf_aws_vpc/pull/58 and the vpc module's `single_nat_gateway` flag would imply that we should be able to have non-HA rds instances in a single AZ...

Comment: @Marcin also, " You can set up Amazon RDS in a Single-AZ database (DB) instance or a Multi-AZ DB instance for high availability requirements." https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-converting-a-single-az-amazon-rds-instance-to-a-multi-az-instance/